# "select an item from" listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i'm working in my first android app so i need some help..

I have a listview wich contends values from a SQLite database, i need to select an item, get it's ID and open a new activity... how to do that?

I have an activity which shows the list of items but i don't know how to select the item and open another activity with the item ID.

```
package chintan.khetiya.sqlite.cursor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import chintan.khetiya.sqlite.cursor.Main_Screen.Contact_Adapter;
import chintan.khetiya.sqlite.cursor.Main_Screen.Contact_Adapter.UserHolder;

public class home_screen extends Activity{

//Button add_btn;
ListView Contact_listview;
ArrayList<Contact> contact_data = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Contact_Adapter cAdapter;
DatabaseHandler db;
String Toast_msg;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.home);
try {
    Contact_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_pedidos);
    Contact_listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    Contact_listview.setClickable(true);

    Set_Referash_Data();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("Error", "" + e);
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Clientes:
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main_Screen.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.Productos:
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Product_Screen.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.Nuevo_Pedido:
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, home_screen.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.Nuevo_Pedido_dentro:
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, nuevo_pedido.class));
            return true;    

        case R.id.salir:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
public void Set_Referash_Data() {
contact_data.clear();
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
ArrayList<Contact> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_Contacts();

for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

    int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
    String name = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
    String mobile = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getPhoneNumber();
    String email = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getEmail();
    Contact cnt = new Contact();
    cnt.setID(tidno);
    cnt.setName(name);
    cnt.setEmail(email);
    cnt.setPhoneNumber(mobile);

    contact_data.add(cnt);
}
db.close();
cAdapter = new Contact_Adapter(home_screen.this, R.layout.listview_pedidos_row,
    contact_data);
Contact_listview.setAdapter(cAdapter);
cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void Show_Toast(String msg) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();
Set_Referash_Data();

}

public class Contact_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
Activity activity;
int layoutResourceId;
Contact user;
ArrayList<Contact> data = new ArrayList<Contact>();

public Contact_Adapter(Activity act, int layoutResourceId,
    ArrayList<Contact> data) {
    super(act, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.activity = act;
    this.data = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    holder = new UserHolder();
    holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_name_txt);
    holder.email = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_email_txt);
    holder.number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_mob_txt);
    //holder.edit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
    //holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
    holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    user = data.get(position);
    //holder.edit.setTag(user.getID());
    //holder.delete.setTag(user.getID());
    holder.name.setText(user.getName());
    holder.email.setText(user.getEmail());
    holder.number.setText(user.getPhoneNumber());
    return row;

}

class UserHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView email;
    TextView number;
    Button edit;
    Button delete;
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to set `setOnItemClickListener` for ListView to get selected item details and move to next Activity as:

```
   Contact_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, 
                                                        int arg2,long arg3) {

                    int selected_row=arg2;
                    // get selected row data  
                    Contact user=(Contact)adapter.getItem(selected_row);

                     //start next activity here
        }
  });
```